# Test if data from array has value Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I want to test if the data array in the code below has content, because when a user gives a packageid (variable in the code below) that doesn't exist i want the else from the "if...else" to be executed. When i put in a packageid that exists everything works fine, but when i put in no number or a number that doesn't exist, the else side does't get evaluated.

```
function getInfoAndStatus(){

sym.$("customer_name").empty();

packageid = $("#tracknrfield").val();

var url = "http://student.howest.be/sylvain.vansteelandt/fedex/server/getPackageTracking.php?id=" + packageid;

$.getJSON(url,function(data){
    if(data && data[0].id){
        $("<span />", {
    text: "Customer name: " + data[0].customer_name + " " + data[0].customer_firstname
}).appendTo(sym.$("customer_name"));
    } else {
            $("<span />", {
    text: "The package with number " + packageid + " has not been found. Please try again."
}).appendTo(sym.$("customer_name"));
    }
});
}

getInfoAndStatus();
```

Comment: So are you asking if it's possible to test if `data` has any values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your javacript console for any errors.  `data` may be null or an empty array.

Adding a check for `console.log(typeof data)` may be useful as well.

Sight unseen, I'd most likely do something like `if (data && data.length > 0)`

Comment: thank you, I used if (data && data.length > 0) and that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you check your console output, I'm betting you'll see an error there.

Your if check should look like:

```
if(data && data[0] && data[0].id)
```

As you may not have an element in your array.